# Get real update performed by Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm not sure about the correct term used for this, but I'm trying to recover the real operation Mongoose performs in my database after the validations.

Example:

Suppose I have the following model -

```
const ChapterSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    pages: Number
})

const BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    chapters: [ChapterSchema]
})

const BooksModel = mongoose.model('Books', BookSchema)
```

If I try to create a new book using this model, with the following command -

```
BooksModel.create({
    title: 1984,
    author: 'George Orwell',
    chapters: [
        { name: 'Chapter 1', pages: 23 }
    ]
})
```

I know for once that Mongoose will not perform a simple `insertOne`, but instead will attempt to parse the values as defined in the schema, (will parse the title to string), and will also include an `_id` in the chapters.

Is there a way to recover the real object Mongoose will be sending to the MongoDB, to perform the `insertOne`? I don't want the created document, but the very object that Mongoose will use as parameter to create said document.